# Using Regex in DataFrame - 5 last characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to change the column type from OBJECT to INT in the following way:

```
df['col name'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

This method worked for other columns but for this one column it does not work because a few percent of rows have a value that can not be converted to INT, which is exactly the "scores" column in which several percent of rows have something like this:

```
1050/1500
```

It should be just:

```
1050
```

I used Regex to find these rows in the following way:

```
df[df["col name"].str.contains("/")]
```

Now I just need to delete the 5 characters from these rows and save the columns, but I don't know how to do it without specifying in which specific row I want to do it.

Comment: Try `df["col name"] = df["col name"].astype(str).str.replace(r'/\d+$', '').astype(int)`

Comment: It works for me

Comment: Great, I posted as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171512/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove `/` and the following digits up to the end of string with `/\d+$` regex. So, cast the data to string first, then replace and then cast to int:

```
df["col name"] = df["col name"].astype(str).str.replace(r'/\d+$', '').astype(int)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WUWTdr/1).

**Details**

- `/` - a `/` char
- `\d+` - any one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve your final goal.

If performance is not an issue, you can use `apply` with a string logic:

```py
df['col name'] = df['col name'].apply(lambda x: int(str(x).split('/')[0]))

Out[30]: 
   colname
0     1050
1     1020
2     1030
3     1000
4     1000
```

Considering **any** last 5 characters, you can use a similar logic

```py
df['colname'] = df['colname'].apply(lambda x: x[:-5] if len(x)>5 else x)

Out[32]: 
  colname
0    1050
1    1020
2    1030
3    1000
4    1000
```

if you really want to use regex, you can use:

```py
df['colname'] = df['colname'].replace('(?:\/[0-9]+)','', regex=True)

Out[33]: 
  colname
0    1050
1    1020
2    1030
3    1000
4    1000
```

If performance matters, we can create a large version of the dataframe and test the performance for the 3 approaches:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(df['colname'].repeat(10000), columns=['colname'])

len(df)

Out[33]
270000

##approach 1
%timeit df['colname'] = df['colname'].apply(lambda x: int(str(x).split('/')[0]))

123 ms ± 1.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

### approach 2
%timeit df['colname'] = df['colname'].apply(lambda x: x[:-5] if len(x)>5 else x)

31.6 ms ± 280 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

## approach 3
%timeit df['colname'] = df['colname'].replace('(?:\/[0-9]+)','', regex=True)

57.3 ms ± 265 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```